# What era of Latin did Horace write in?

Tags: horatius

What era of Latin did Horace write in? Did he write in the era of Old Latin, Classical Latin, or Vulgar Latin? I have tried to look this up and all I could find was that Horace was a Latin lyric poet and satirist. There are no mentions of what type of Latin Horace wrote in whatsoever!

I need to know this for my next question!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Horace, or [Quintus Horatius Flaccus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horace) as he is known in Latin, wrote in Classical Latin.
He lived 65–8 BCE, whereas the era of [Classical Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_Latin) is considered to be roughly 75 BCE–300 CE.
As his entire life falls within this period, he should be considered a classical writer.

Horace is among the most highly esteemed writers of ancient Rome.
You could well say that he is one of the reasons this era is regarded classical.
The classical era is often defined so that it includes the authors we want to consider classical, so this is a case of chickens and eggs.
However you interpret things, it seems uncontroversial by any definition that Horace wrote his works in Classical Latin.